# querySelector select attributes that starts with "data-"

Tags: javascript, queryselector

This is a simple doubt, I have in my HTML many attributes that starts with `data-`:

```
<span data-something="some"></span>
<p data-some="some"></p>
<div data-a-thing="some"></div>
<a data-other-thing="some"></a>
<section data-some-attribute="some"></section>
<span data-asd="some"></span>
<p  data-some-invented-attribute="some"></p>
```

I want to select all tags whose attributes starts with: `data-*`, I want to use RegExp but isn't possible, is there any way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623353/queryselector-get-elements-where-attribute-starts-with-xxx same question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to select dynamic attributes with a single selector. But you could select all elements and filter those by `attributes` that have one that starts with `data`:

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('*')]
    .filter(elm => [...elm.attributes].some(
      attrib => attrib.name.startsWith('data')
    ))
);
```

```html
<span>don't select me</span>
<span data-something="some"></span>
<p data-some="some"></p>
<div data-a-thing="some"></div>
<a data-other-thing="some"></a>
<section data-some-attribute="some"></section>
<span data-asd="some"></span>
<p data-some-invented-attribute="some"></p>
```

Another method, using `dataset`:

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('*')]
    .filter(elm => Object.keys(elm.dataset).length)
);
```

```html
<span>don't select me</span>
<span data-something="some"></span>
<p data-some="some"></p>
<div data-a-thing="some"></div>
<a data-other-thing="some"></a>
<section data-some-attribute="some"></section>
<span data-asd="some"></span>
<p data-some-invented-attribute="some"></p>
```

Comment: You were right about my answer. Deleted it.