# Error handling when user modifies the wire:model by inspect element in the browser

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

I'm using `livewire` and `Laravel` in my forms.

A problem that I noticed is that if we have an input like this:

```html
<input type="text" wire:model.debounce.500ms="first_name" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control"/>
```

Then when user modifies the `wire:model.debounce.500ms` attribute value or totally removes that in inspect element, after typing into that input because `livewire` can't find the model name so it throws an error and the error will be shown in a modal that says this:

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Str::studly(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-project\example\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\helpers.php on line 13 and exactly 1 expected
```

So I want to handle these errors.  I know I can change `APP_DEBUG` in `.env` file to false but again it shows the error modal saying there is a `500 error` but I don't want the user's manipulations affects the livewire or at least not to show these modals and just detect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for mutations on your inputs.

We can use `document.evaluate` to find all `wire:model` elements (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41623808/14793358))

```js
let attributeObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // Do something
});

let wireModels = document.evaluate('//*/attribute::*[starts-with(name(), "wire:model")]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (let i = 0; i < wireModels.snapshotLength; i++) {
    const element = wireModels.snapshotItem(i).ownerElement
    attributeObserver.observe(element, {
        attributes: true,
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried to get the modified element and set the modified attribute to the old value but the `oldValue` key that `mutation` variable returns, is null

Comment: And another problem is that it will run `MutationObserver` when the page reloads.

Comment: Have you set `attributeOldValue` to `true` in your config?